# Define custom equation with text shortcut in MS word equation editor

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

I'm currently typing out lots of equations in MS word and I would like to be able to define custom textual shortcuts for equations I enter often.

For example, I often type `lim_(n->\infty)`. I would like to type: `\limni`. (this is a simple case, it can get more tedious).

Is there any way I can achieve this? I have found how to save new equations to the gallary, I have not found how to map the text `\limni` to that saved equation.

Comment: Did you ever think to something about [TexMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) + LaTex? In LaTex you can do your own macro...

Comment: @Hastur I would love to use LaTex, but I'm usually doing homework and I'm required to hand it in in Word

Comment: A lot of equation and Equation editor it is not a good marriage... IMHO... maybe you can add a `Sci` before that `Word`...

Comment: __Workaround:__ you can use the automatic corrector to correct `\limni` in the LaTex expression for the limit, e.g. `$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$`, then the button _“Toggle between TeX/LaTeX and MathType equations”_ or even better a keyboard shortcut for that button...

Comment: Ok it exists a tab [MathAutoCorrect](https://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/choosing_math_autocorrect_options_.html) In the AutoCorrect dialog box, that you can use for your intent... but really if there's a lot of equation think how to use LaTex...

Comment: @Hastur Thanks! The "MathAutoCorrect" works somewhat :) for some reason it does not work exactly as if I typed the text on my own (weird - probably a bug). But it does help.

Comment: You're welcome... Btw I added it as answer too, so it will remain for other people too. ps> use LaTex... if you want with Lyx,TexMaxer,WinEdt whatever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see somehow a **workaround** family:

- Use [MathAutoCorrect](https://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/choosing_math_autocorrect_options_.html)

  > The Math AutoCorrect tab of the AutoCorrect dialog box **lets you to control whether and where to have AutoCorrect** replace math terms with math symbols. If you use math in your documents, Math AutoCorrect can be a great timesaver; if you don't use math, turn it off by clearing the Replace text as you type check box on the Math AutoCorrect tab.

  you can define your expression and the substitution.
  e.g. `\limni` for `$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$`
- You can use globally the Autocorrect and thenthe button *“Toggle between TeX/LaTeX and MathType equations”* or better a shortcut from the keyboard that you can assign in advance.

---

IMHO, **the best solution remains to use LaTex**  (maybe with [TexMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker))
if you have to handle so many equations...